# Prove $\frac{n^2+2}{(2 \cdot n^2)-1} \to \frac{1}{2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, limits

> Prove $\frac{n^2+2}{(2 \cdot n^2)-1} \to \frac{1}{2}$ for $n \to \infty$.

I've been looking at this for hours! Also, sorry I don't have the proper notation.

This is where I'm at:

$$
\left| \frac{n^2 + 2}{2 \cdot n^2 - 1} - \frac{1}{2}\right| = \left| \frac{5}{4 \cdot n^2 - 2} \right|
$$

I thought I was supposed to get to the point where I can say $1/n <n$, but I can only get to $1/n-1$ so that can't be the right approach or I'm missing something.

A friend says to make $n > \frac{5}{\varepsilon^2}$ but I''m not sure what to do with that tip.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Now you can use, say, $\frac{5}{2(2n^2-1)}<\frac{5}{2n^2-1}\le\frac{5}{2n^2-n^2}=\frac{5}{n^2}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might find it easier to write
$$\dfrac{n^2+2}{2n^2-1} = \dfrac{1}{2}  \times \dfrac{2n^2+4}{2n^2-1} = \dfrac{1}{2} + \dfrac{5}{4n^2-2}$$ and note you can make $\dfrac{5}{4n^2-2}$ as small as you want by making $n$ large enough.

If you must use epsilon-delta or epsilson-$N_0$, then note that $\dfrac{5}{4n^2-2} \lt \varepsilon $ if $\dfrac5\varepsilon \lt 4n^2 -2$ which is true if $n \gt \sqrt{\dfrac12+\dfrac{5}{4\varepsilon}}$

Comment: Thank you for your responses! I feel like I am supposed to use epsilon and n naught. That's what's tripping me up. Can you help me solve this rigorously with that approach?

Comment: @bamboozled: it is not hard to find an $ N_0$ - see edit

Comment: I read the section and did this on my own but I still don't understand. How do we get to the point where we have n < n naught < epsilon or something of that format? How are we squeezing this series to find it's limit?

Comment: If $n \gt N_0 = \sqrt{\dfrac12+\dfrac{5}{4\varepsilon}}$ then $\dfrac{1}{2} \lt \dfrac{n^2+2}{2n^2-1} \lt \dfrac{1}{2} +\varepsilon$, and so $\left|\dfrac{n^2+2}{2n^2-1} - \dfrac{1}{2}\right| \lt \varepsilon$

Comment: How do we know n^2 + 2 / 2n^2-1 > 1/2?

Comment: See my first line $\dfrac{n^2+2}{2n^2-1} = \dfrac{1}{2} + \dfrac{5}{4n^2-2}$ which is a calculation you also seem to have done

Comment: Here's my current understanding:

Answer (score 5):

Naively, when $n \to \infty$, $n^2+2$ is like $n^2$ and $2n^2-1$ is like $2n^2$, so the limit should be $\frac{n^2}{2n^2} = \frac{1}{2}$. To make this rigorous, the easiest is probably to divide by $n^2$ the top and bottom :
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{n^2+2}{2n^2-1} = \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1+2/n^2}{2-1/n^2}
$$
Now we know that $1/n^2 \to 0$ when $n \to \infty$ so the usual limit rules show that the answer is indeed $1/2$.

Answer (score 0):

$\left|\frac{n^2+2}{2n^2-1} - \frac {1}{2}\right| =  \frac{5}{4n^2-2}$

Let $\epsilon>0$ be given. Let $n_0$ be the smallest integer such that $n\geq n_0> \sqrt{\frac{5}{4\epsilon} + \frac 12}$. Equivalently, $\epsilon>\frac{5}{4n^2-2}$.

Thus, $\left|\frac{n^2+2}{2n^2-1} - \frac {1}{2}\right|< \epsilon$, for all $n\geq n_0$.